# Jfrog Artifactory OSS - Router Service Error - UpCloud

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to setup JFrog Artifactory OSS in UpCloud Windows VM. While starting up the service i am getting **"Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Get http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/system/ping"**

I have tried other solutions mentioning that i might need to set my IPV4 in system.yaml or 127.0.0.1. I have tried both and added its mapping in Windows host file. But it not getting resovled and always stuck in same issue. For experimentation, i have also disabled Windows firewall but still no luck :(

Windows : Windows Server 2019

Artifactory version : 7.3.x

Comment: Hi can  you share the system.yaml  you have used,  pls? Also  check if  there are  any exceptions in access log?

Comment: Yes there are some exception regarding derby. Saying another instance of derby already booted server. Then it starts the server and load default derby configs. After that router error pops up.

Comment: Let me get that log and i will share it here.

Comment: Sure. Also please can you confirm if this is an Upgrade scenario or a fresh install?